# Oracle Forms Builder - change to window in another form

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

We have two forms so far, and need to switch from window1 in from1 (which is login screen) to windowX in formX using button (trigger code below):

```
begin
  show_window('windowX');
  go_block('some_block_in_formX');
end;
```

This gives error FRM-41052: Cannot find Window: invalid ID

So question is, should I add formX into show_window parameter in certain way or is there another approach? Thank you.

Please note, that forms are in different files.

Answer (score 1):

> that forms are in different files.

If the forms are different files, you need to call the other form using [open form/call form/newform](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Forms_FAQ#What_is_the_difference_between_CALL_FORM.2C_NEW_FORM_and_OPEN_FORM.3F) - whatever suits your needs.

`show_window/go_block` sequence can be used only when you're moving to different windows/blocks of the *same* form - and the error message

> error FRM-41052: Cannot find Window: invalid ID

is complaining that it can't go to that Window because it's in a *different* form.

Answer (score 0):

Each form effectively has a private namespace for all its windows, blocks, items, etc - and your code always runs within the context of a single form.

To solve this, you'll need a form parameter, plus some code in the other form, e.g.:

1. in formX, add a parameter ACTION
2. in form1, pass the value 'XYZ' to ACTION
3. in formX, in the `WHEN-NEW-FORM-INSTANCE` trigger, check if `:PARAMETER.ACTION = 'XYZ'`, and if so, do your show_window and go_block. Copy the same code to your `WHEN-WINDOW-ACTIVATED` trigger.

Of course, you'll need to think about the name of the parameter (e.g. ACTION) and value ('XYZ') that will make sense to people maintaining your forms in the future.